# How can I create keyboard shortcuts to move to previous / next full-screen app?

Tags: macos, keyboard, spaces, mission-control

I'm trying to add keyboard shortcut to move to prev/next full-screen app.

I'm now @ Keyboard > 'Keyboard shortcuts', there is no options under 'Mission Control'. And I have no idea of what to add in 'Application shortcuts' for it.

In addition, I would like to change the shortcut in 'Mission Control' which 'Move left/right a space', but doesn't seem like I can change it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

> "In addition, I would like to change the shortcut in 'Mission Control'
>   which 'Move left/right a space', but doesn't seem like I can change
>   it."

I believe I can help answer this part.

At first I thought that a drop down would appear, but it does not. All you have to do, if you want to use keyboard shortcuts (not sure about trackpad or mouse) is hit the key once the item is selected.

[image]
Above is a screenshot of the menu with default settings.

[image]
Below is a screenshot of the menu with moving to the right changed to "."

So, to recap:
Highlight item to change, double click on current shortcut symbol (to highlight it), immediately hit new key for the shortcut.

Hope this helps some!

Comment: Just a quick note here: originally, I also did not have any options under "Mission Control." In order to fix this (I believe this worked) I went to the Mission Control tab in the Main preferences window, and changed some of the shortcuts from there. Then I went back into the Keyboard settings, and they had appeared. I could be wrong about this part, because I had been tinkering for a while on the issue.